# Why is this code working despite passing an uninstantiated variable as an argument?

Tags: c#, .net

Here's the syntax for using `TryParse`

```
int a;
bool success = Int32.TryParse("0",out a);
```

But how on earth could this work? The variable `a` hasn't been instantiated!

Comment: that should read: `bool success = Int32.TryParse("0", out a);`

Comment: Basically, by using an out parameter, you are telling C# that `a` will be instantiated or assigned to by the method, in which case, it does not need to be instantiated at the time the method is called

Comment: Paul -- you should make that an answer, no?

Comment: @PaulGriffin: please don't post .NET 1.1 links. Readers wind up stuck in a maze of .NET 1.1 links when they follow links from your link.

Comment: @John Saunders: Egads, sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `out` parameter does not need to be instantiated in the calling method. In fact, any value it had in the calling method would be overwritten by the called method.

Example:

```
public static bool MyTryParse(string value, out int result){
    int hold;
    if (int.TryParse(value, out hold)){
        result = hold;
        return true;
    }

    // Comment out the following line and you'll get a compile error
    result = default(int); // This method MUST set result
    return false;
}
```

As you can see, even if the caller set some value on the parameter, that value will be overwritten.

Further, note that this works in exactly the same way if a reference type is used.

---

From "**[out (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx)**":

> The **out** keyword causes arguments to be passed by reference.
>
> ...
>
> Although variables passed as out arguments do not have to be initialized before being passed, the called method is required to assign a value before the method returns.
>
> ...

something I didn't know:

> Overloading can be done, however, if one method takes a **ref** or **out** argument and the other uses neither, like this:

```
class OutOverloadExample
{
    public void SampleMethod(int i) { }
    public void SampleMethod(out int i) { i = 5; }
}
```

Comment: a primitive type is never instantiated, using an out parameter...you're passing the reference and not the value that's why it is overwritten

Comment: Sorry, no, that's not the reason. An `out` parameter will _always_ be assigned in the called method. Even for a reference type parameter, any value the parameter has in the calling method _must_ be overwritten by the called method.

Answer (score 1):

The semantics of an `out` parameter are that the variable does not need to be assigned previously when calling the method. The compiler marks the variable as "definitely assigned", in the parlance of the C# spec, which means it is legal to use in later expressions because it must have been initialized with a value inside the method.

This is rule is stated in section 5.1.6 of the C# specification:

> A variable need not be definitely assigned before it can be passed as an output parameter in a function member or delegate invocation.

This is different from a `ref` parameter which the must be definitely assigned before being passed to a method but the method will be able to modify the variable.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing using the  `out` keyword is passing by reference your `a`. Look at the generated IL:

[image]

if you see at line IL_0006 there is an instruction called [ldloca.s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldloca_s(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Loads the address of the local variable at a specific index onto the evaluation stack, short form.

To summarize: out causes the argument to be passed by reference so when you pass your variable to TryParse, to the variable `a` is assigned the value of the string your passing once it has been converted.

hope it helps.

Comment: This is not because it's a value type - it's because the `TryParse` method will always set the parameter value.

Comment: @JohnSaunders it's true, my point was twofold: a primitive does not need to be instantiated plus passing the parameter using out means passing it by reference

Comment: and could you explain me how the called method can assign a value to the passed type? I guess it uses the same storage location for the variable...true that using out doesn't require you to assign/instantiate the variable before hand but output parameters are very much like reference parameters

Comment: Ok, I guess it _does_ mean that it is called by reference, but please be sure not to confuse "call by reference" and "reference type".

Comment: I rephrased but I never mentioned a "reference type". I was just explaining at IL level what happens using an out keyword and honestly I believe 2 downvotes are a bit unfair given that what I wrote is not wrong

Comment: I do recommend you remove the paragraph about "primitive type", which is not even relevant. In fact, I suspect you meant to say "value type", which is _still_ not relevant. It doesn't need to be set (or instantiated) in the calling method because the called method must do so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72715/discussion-between-johnfield-and-john-saunders).